# If every map $I\to S^1$ is nullhomotopic, then $\pi_1(S^1)$ is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be contractible and $f\colon X\to Y$ be any map. Then we have a homotopy $H\colon X\times I\to X$ such that $H(x,0)=x$ and $H(x,1)=x_0$ for every $x\in X$ and some fixed $x_0\in X$. Consider the function $f\circ H\colon X\times I\to Y$. It is continuous being the composition of continuous functions. Further, $(f\circ H)(x,0)=f(H(x,0))=f(x)$ and $(f\circ H)(x,1)=f(H(x,1))=f(x_0)=:y_0$. Therefore, $f\circ H$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $y_0$. This proves

> If $X$ is contractible, then any map $f\colon X\to Y$ is nullhomotopic.

In particular, this would means any map $I\to S^1$ is nullhomotopic. Doesn't this imply that $\pi_1(S^1)-0$? Where has my reasoning gone wrong?

Comment: $\pi_1(Y)$ counts maps $S^1\to Y$ up to homotopy. So $I\to S^1$ does not give information about $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely all maps $I \to X$ are nullhomotopic. But this has nothing to do  with the fundamental group of $X$. In fact
$$\pi_1(X,x_0)$$
requires the choice of a basepoint $x_0$ and consists of all *path homotopy classes of closed paths $u : I \to X$ at $x_0$*.

A closed path $u$ at $x_0$ is one satisfying $u(0) = u(1) = x_0$ and a path homotopy between two paths $u, v : I \to X$ having the same initial point $p_0 = u(0) = v(0)$ and the same terminal point $p_1 = u(1) = v(1)$ is a homotopy $H : I \times I \to X$ from $u$ to $v$ *keeping $\partial I = \{0,1\}$ fixed* which means that $H(i,t) = p_i$ for all $t \in I$, $i = 0,1$.

Of course any two $u, v : I \to X$ are homotopic, but even if they are closed paths at $x_0$ there is no reason to expect that they are homotopic rel. $\partial I$.

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear to me: So, I have produced a homotopy $H\colon I\times I\to S^1$ between, say, the generator $[\gamma]\in\pi_1(S^1,0)$ and the constant loop identity element $[e_{0}]\in\pi_1(S^1,0)$, but the homotopy is not path homotopic, so in $\pi_1(S^1,0)$ they aren't equal.

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds Exactly. No homotopy between $\gamma$ and $e_0$ keeps $\partial I$ fixed.